# Multiple buttons at center of screen vertically with Autolayout in iOS

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to add 3 buttons with same height and same width at the center of screen vertically. I am using auto layout.

I tried by selecting all buttons and set the constraint to `align center vertically`, but it's not working.

[image]

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q=vertical+align+objective+c+ios+autolayout&oq=vertical+align+objective+c+ios+autolay&gs_l=serp.1.0.33i21k1.4934.9844.0.11669.8.8.0.0.0.0.327.1524.0j3j3j1.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..1.3.770.h9s8LTbLpAo

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: put 3 buttons in a uiview and add constraints required and make that uiview center vertically in superview

Comment: put screen shot current and original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

1 select the Button2 give hive constraints like first image.see the constraints window.

2 give the constraints to butto1.
[image]

3 give the constraints to butto3.

you can see all there button constraints in window.

Comment: Great  @User_1191              :)

Answer (score 1):

try this constraint:

[image]
[image]

Step: 1> [image]

Step: 2> [image]

Step: 3> [image]

Answer (score 0):

add your buttons in `UIView` and set `top,leading,trailing and fixed height` constraints to every button. set constraint for views like `center Y (vertically in container), center X (horizontally in container), fixed width,fixed height`. make sure that your view's height is not more than it fits all buttons with padding between them.